# Interchange of integral and differentiation

Tags: probability, expected-value, measure-theory

Say I have 2 continuous bivariate distributions (for example bivariate log normal and bivariate weibull) which have joint density functions as: $f_1(x,y,\theta)$ and  $f_2(x,y,\alpha).$

Now I want to do something like:

\begin{align*}
\bigg[\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\log\bigg({f_{2}(x,y;\alpha)}\bigg)f_{1}(x,y;\theta) \,dx\,dy\bigg]
=\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} E_{f_1}(\log f_2(X,Y,\alpha))
\end{align*}

I know by DCT I can do that but to check the condition of the integrand in LHS being dominated by some integrable function of X and Y is a tedious task. Can we check this condition by some alternate way which makes it easier to do so?

Comment: (1) What is "DCT"? (2) The answer ought to depend on the details, making it difficult to respond to the general question you ask.   (It shouldn't be difficult to construct a family of distributions for which the task is arbitrarily tedious...) Is the example you give the specific problem you face?

Comment: 1) DCT :"Dominated convergence theorem"

Comment: 2) let us say we have f1 as bivariate log normal and f2 as bivariate normal

Comment: Those are easy: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule.

Comment: Lebiniz fails when we talk about integration in infinite region.

Comment: I don't see why.  If that troubles you, there are no difficulties limiting these integrals to large finite regions and approximating them, because the derivatives of the densities asymptotically vanish.